# Как написать юнит-тест на замыкание?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты

не пойму, как такую функцию вызвать в юнит-тесте?

```
export function myFunction(val, min, max) {
    return function (e) {
        ...
        return result;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myFunction(1, 2, 3)(456) == 789
```